# gtsummary - way to list individual elements in a 2x2 table?

Tags: r, gtsummary

In a 2x2 table, the usual presentation is that the cell contains the count of the elements in that cell, the sum of the elements, or some other summary statistic. But sometimes, I need to see the list of values in that particular cell. For example, one axis could be sex (male/female) and the other axis is favorite ice cream (chocolate / vanilla). But instead of counting up all the records that are male/choc 7, male/van 4, female/choc 3, female/van 8, I want to list the names of the people in each cell. For example, male/choc would be Daniel, Jason, Narinder and Hollis and these names would populate the male / choc cell. My question is this. Is there a way that the typical output of gtsummary can be altered to include individual data like this, not just summary data.